# Scoreboard of how many chicken players kill

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I tried this:

```
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay list minecraft.killed:minecraft.chicken
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start by creating an actual scoreboard objective before you can display it. To create the objective, start by running:

```
/scoreboard objectives add ChickensKilled minecraft.killed:minecraft.chicken
```

Once you have an actual `ChickensKilled` objective with the appropriate criteria, you can display it using setdisplay:

```
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay list ChickensKilled
```